# ThreadStatic атрибут, тонкости использования

Tags: c#, атрибуты

Для меня непонятен этот момент из документации:

> Для полей с атрибутом ThreadStatic начальные значения указывать не нужно, поскольку такая инициализация происходит только один раз, при выполнении конструктора класса, и затрагивает только один поток. Если не указать начальные значения, полю, относящемуся к типу значения, будет присвоено значение по умолчанию, а полю, относящемуся к ссылочному типу — значение null.

и

> Следует учитывать, что любой код конструктора класса будет работать с первым потоком в первом контексте, получающим доступ к полю. Поля во всех других потоках и во всех других контекстах в пределах того же домена приложения будут инициализированы значением null (Nothing в Visual Basic), если они имеют ссылочные типы, или значениями по умолчанию, если они имеют типы значения. Поэтому не следует полагаться на инициализацию статических полей потока конструкторами классов. Напротив, следует избегать инициализации статических полей потока и предполагать, что они инициализированы значениями null (Nothing) или значениями по умолчанию.

Допустим у нас есть поле:

```
[ThreadStatic]
public static int Timeout = 50000;
```

При обращении к полю из первого потока поле отдаст значение 50000, а при обращении из второго - отдаст 0? Я правильно понимаю?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так и есть. При обращению в том потоке, где объект был создан, прочитается 50000, а в других — 0. Но полагаться на это не стоит: если объект используется в нескольких потоках, не всегда легко отследить, в каком же потоке он был реально создан (и это может быть источником тонких, редко проявляющихся ошибок).

Кроме того, ваш код проиграет в читаемости: вы ведь пишете `Timeout = 50000`, и читатель вашего кода должен всё время держать в голове «... но только в том потоке, в котором этот объект был создан».

Поэтому лучше, как и советует MSDN, вовсе не инициализировать объект. При этом его значение в начале будет равно `default(int)`, то есть 0, во *всех* потоках.

---

Обновление: конечно, инициализация пройдёт не в том потоке, где был создан *объект* (объектов ведь много), а в котором выполнился *статический* конструктор. То есть обычно это поток, в котором создаётся *первый* объект. Спасибо @MaLS за наводку.

---

Заметьте, что существует более удобное решение, если вы пользуетесь .NET 4 или старше: класс [ThreadLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx). Для него вы можете легко установить начальное значение в каждом из потоков:

```
public static ThreadLocal<int> Timeout = new ThreadLocal<int>(() => 50000);
```

Лямбда-функция будет испоьзована для вычисления начального значения в *каждом* из потоков. Она может, в принципе, в каждом потоке возвращать своё, отдельное значение.

Comment: VladD, хотелось бы прояснить еще один момент. Будет ли логически правильно оставить все поля, помеченные атрибутом [ThreadStatic] не инициализированными, и инициализировать их (присваивать уже реальные значения) в отдельном методе, после объявления класса? На данный момент есть библиотека, в которой несколько тысяч static полей уже инициализированных данными. Я переделываю ее под многопоточное выполнение.

Comment: @z668: Сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: @z668: Подождите, вопрос: а библиотека, которую вы переделываете, на C++? И там они объявлены как static?

Comment: VladD, нет, библиотека на управляемом коде, написана на C# под .NET 4.5

Comment: @z668: Хорошо. А значения этих переменных будут меняться, или только считываться? Потому что если только считываться, достаточно `const`.

Comment: VladD, значения в процессе выполнения будут меняться. const или readonly не подойдут. С ThreadLocal понял, спасибо.

Comment: @z668: С другой стороны, если вам нужны отдельные переменные в каждом из потоков, может быть, имеет смысл просто в каждом потоке завести экземпляр какого-нибудь подходящего класса? Thread local — это достаточно низкоуровневое решение. Подумайте, может быть стоит улучшить архитектуру. (Или нет, вам как разработчику виднее.)

Comment: VladD, спасибо за совет. Но в моем случае это отнимет очень много времени. Библиотека большая, без документации и банальных комментариев в коде. Попутно нужно будет прочесть несколько rfc по сопутствующим протоколам.

Comment: @z668: Эх. Понимаю. Удачи вам!

Comment: @VladD _"При обращению в том потоке, где объект был создан, прочитается 50000, а в других — 0."_ я сомневаюсь в этом утверждение. Так как поле статическое, то ему будет присвоено значение в потоке в котором вызывается статический конструктор, а не в котором создаётся объект.

Comment: @MaLS: Тьфу. Точно. Перепутал object constructor и class constructor. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Если статическое поле класса с атрибутом `ThreadStatic` имеет начальное значение, то это значение будет присвоено полю только в том потоке, который вызывает статический конструктор класса, в остальных потоках данное поле будет иметь значение по умолчанию.