# Отдельное содержимое счетчика для каждого потока C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм, многопоточность, счетчики

- Есть класс, представляющий некий API-функционал.
  В коде класса есть счетчик, меняющийся после каждого вызова одного из методов API. Счетчик определяет количество элементов, полученных при вызове метода API и используется "для внутреннего потребления".
- Если вызывать методы из разных потоков, значение счетчика не будет актуальным.
- Есть идея реализовать счетчик как dictionary

Подробности. Есть [API для ВК](http://vknet.github.io/vk/). Компилирую из модифицированных исходников. Суть изменений - каждый вызов метода, получающий список чего-либо, например список объектов сообщений, из json-ответа сохраняет в счётчик ОБЩЕЕ число всех сообщений. Нужно для того, чтобы работали самописные методы вида GetAll*, которые вызывают оригинальный метод API несколько раз, с нужным смещением, т.к. API контакта не позволяет получить всё за один запрос. Счётчик нужен для определения необходимого числа вызовов.

Но есть один момент. Хотелось бы оставить возможность получать значение этого счетчика вне методов API. Альтернативой вижу только добавление переменной вида "out int totalCount" к каждому методу оригинального API, а это не есть хорошо.

---

***Как правильно это реализовать?
Или, возможно, есть другой, более удачный способ решения таких задач?***

Comment: Можно использовать [ThreadStatic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx) или [ThreadLocal<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd642243.aspx).

Comment: Советую почитать: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420841/threadstatic-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @z668, насколько я понимаю, если начальное значение счетчика должно быть равным нулю, мне не о чем беспокоиться?

Comment: @АлексейЕфремов, да.

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо, но думаю, было бы неплохо, если бы кто-то оформил вариант с ThreadStatic как ответ.

Comment: @АлексейЕфремов почти всегда есть _другой, более удачный способ для решения таких задач_, нежели использование ThreadStatic / ThreadLocal, но этот ответ невозможно дать, пока не будет пояснение о том, как этот счетчик используется.

Comment: @PavelHritonenko! Попробую объяснить. Есть API для ВК. [ссылка] (https://vknet.github.io/vk/). Компилирую из модифицированных исходников. Суть изменений - каждый вызов метода, получающий список чего-либо, например список объектов сообщений, из json-ответа сохраняет в счётчик ОБЩЕЕ число всех сообщений. Нужно для того, чтобы работали самописные методы вида GetAll*, которые вызывают оригинальный метод API несколько раз, с нужным смещением, т.к. API контакта не позволяет получить всё за один запрос. Счётчик нужен для определения необходимого числа вызовов.

Comment: Для этого не нужны ThreadStatic поля. Требуется сохранять этот счетчик не на "поток", а на "итерацию". Этот счетчик можно инкапсулировать в локальной переменной метода, который возвращает `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @АлексейЕфремов перенесите свое пояснение в тело вопроса - оно полностью меняет суть.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого случая не нужны `ThreadStatic` поля. Требуется сохранять этот счетчик не на "поток", а на "итерацию". Этот счетчик можно инкапсулировать в локальной переменной метода, который возвращает `IEnumerable<T>`

Приведенный ниже код не является рабочим, или даже компилирующимся, но из него можно понять, что я имел ввиду под своим ответом.

```
public static IEnumerable<User> GetAllFollowers(long userId) {
  const int pageSize = 50;
  var startRow = 0;
  while (true) {
    var page = _vkApi.GetFollowers(userId, startRow, pageSize);
    if (page.Length != 0) {
      foreach(var user in page) yield user;
      startRow += page.Length;
    }
    else
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Если вам не сложно, перенесите всё объяснение (и причешите его в связный ответ), хорошо? Обычно в комментарии никто не заглядывает, так что ценность ответа, опирающегося на комментарии, невысока.

Comment: @VladD сделаю сразу, как будет исправлено исходное сообщение, чтобы не играть в испорченный телефон, чтобы ответ был на заданный вопрос.

Comment: Исправлено (только что).

Comment: @PavelHritonenko, есть один момент. Хотелось бы оставить возможность получать значение этого счетчика вне методов API. Альтернативой вижу только добавление переменной вида "out int totalCount" к каждому методу оригинального API, а это не есть хорошо.

Comment: @АлексейЕфремов "Хотелось бы оставить возможность получать значение этого счетчика вне методов API." - зачем? В каком виде? Как использоваться будет? Или чем в таком случае не устраивают оригинальные методы VK-API? Можно для них написать partial-application обертки, которые будут "прятать" от клиента часть параметров исходного метода. То есть ровно та же ситуация - я не смогу помочь, пока не будет ясно использование этих счетчиков.

Comment: @PavelHritonenko, для того, чтобы не переписывать каждый метод, просто добавляя в него "out int totalCount". А оригинальные методы расстраивают именно отсутствием в результатах этого значения.

Comment: @АлексейЕфремов Я не про то, что нужно сделать "out totalCount", а про намерения - зачем оно нужно, как планируется использовать это значение, для каких целей. Каждый из исходных методов уже возвращает коллекцию, у которой есть размер. P.S. Править код 3rd party библиотек - очень плохо.

Comment: @PavelHritonenko, смотрите. На стене, к примеру, есть очень много (ну пусть 1235) сообщений. Но методом wall.get можно получать только по 100 штук максимум за раз. При этом при каждом выполнении метода wall.get в сыром JSON ответе возвращается и ОБЩЕЕ число объектов стены, т.е. 1235, при этом это значение НЕ будет совпадать с размером возвращаемой коллекции. А использоваться будет во многих случаях. Делаю вокруг вышеуказанного API систему поиска похожих постов и людей лайкнувших эти посты. Почти рекомендательная система, но немного для других целей, и счетчик будет много где полезен.

Comment: @АлексейЕфремов "много где полезен" - это не ответ. Подозреваю, что требуется рядом с каждым сообщением иметь его индекс в общем списке. Опять же, стоит обратить внимание, что между запросами к API на сервере данные могут меняться, что может привести к изменению индексов и появлению дублирующихся записей на разных страницах.