# Работа атрибута ThreadStatic в асинхронных вызовых

Tags: c#, .net, асинхронность

Есть библиотека, переделанная под многопоточное выполнение атрибутами `ThreadStatic`. Есть желание сделать ее асинхронной. Но, как быть со статическими полями и методами? Ведь новый поток не будет создан, и контекст не поменяется...

Это продолжение к прошлому вопросу о атрибуте: [ThreadStatic атрибут, тонкости использования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420841/threadstatic-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: ThreadStatic - плохая идея в качестве основы для "многопоточного выполнения". Можете привести пример кода? Без него непонятно, зачем вы используете именно статические поля, а не, скажем, обычные параметры, или просто отдельные объекты для каждого из обрабатываемых заданий.

Comment: @PashaPash, представьте сетевой клиент, половина которого написана на основе статических методов и полей. Библиотека изначально делалась без наследования (которое встречается очень редко). Соответственно пример кода не могу привести по причине того, что код из половины библиотеки никто разгребать не будет.

Comment: Возможно есть вариант\ы, сделать статические поля в классе уникальными для каждого асинхронного вызова этого класса?

Comment: Самое простое (точнее, реальное) решение - сделать эти поля нестатическими. И сделать нестатическими методы, которые к ним обращаются, и все методы вверх по цепочке. Тогда они будут уникальными для каждого асинхронного вызова класса. Т.е. просто уберите статику, пробросьте нужные вещи параметрами - и все заработает.

Comment: Вам нужно вот что: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html

Comment: @VladD, Вы не могли бы, если есть время и желание, перевести статью? К сожалению не нашел локализованную Concurrency in C# Cookbook, а очень хотелось бы почитать. Спасибо.

Comment: @Alexis: Попробую вытащить из статьи ответ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Решение можно найти в статье Стивена Клири [Implicit Async Context](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html). Я попробую пересказать суть.

---

Итак, в обыкновеном, не-async-коде, любая цепочка вызовов функций находится всё время в одном и том же потоке. Таким образом, thread static-переменные представляют собой вариант глобальных переменных, которые не подвержены многопоточным проблемам (но имеют проблему с рекурсивным вызовом, конечно).

В случае async-функции, выполнение может «прыгать» между потоками, таким образом, thread local нам не подходит. Что же у нас есть в замену? Что сохраняется при смене потока?

Ответ такой: это «логический контекст вызова», который можно использовать при помощи [`CallContext.LogicalGetData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext.logicalgetdata.aspx) и [`CallContext.LogicalSetData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext.logicalsetdata.aspx). Эти вызовы позволяют записать и считать объект по его строковому имени.

Обычный контекс вызова, доступный через `CallContext.GetData` и `CallContext.SetData`, по сути работает как thread local-данные, что не подходит для async-методов.

Логический контекст вызова прикреплён к `ExecutionContext`'у. Это означает, что на него не влияет `ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)`. Возможности «отписаться» от сохранения логического контекста нет, он *всегда* будет передаваться по всем продолжениям (continuations) асинхронного метода.

Когда async-метод начинает выполняться, он сигнализирует логическому контексту вызова активировать отложенное копирование (копирование при фактических измениях). Это значит, что текущий логический контекст не подменяется в реальности немедленно, но как только ваш код вызовет `CallContext.LogicalSetData`, логический контекст копируется в новый, который становится текущим, и изменения происходят уже на новом контексте. (Обратите внимание: такое поведение имеет место только начиная с .NET 4.5.)

Это значит, что логический контекст работает как стек: изменения в контексте (на верхнем уровне!), внесённые вызываемой функцией, не видны в вызывающей функции. Напротив, изменения, сделанные вызывающей функцией, видны в вызываемой функции.

Копирование логического контекста вызова не глубокое. Проще всего думать о логическом контексте как об `IDictionary<string, object>`; при копировании создаётся копия словаря с теми же ключами и ссылками на объекты-значения. Новый словарь ссылается на старые объекты.

Вследствие этого важно **не изменять** значения внутри объектов, полученных из контекста! Если вам нужно изменить значение, создайте новый объект, и запишите его в контекст при помощи `CallContext.LogicalSetData`. Лучше всего использовать неизменяемые типы данных, чтобы не поменять значение случайно.

Разумеется, если вы хотите получить данные, изменённые во вложенной функции, вы должны делать всё наоборот: передать изменяемый объект, и изменять значения, записанные в нём. Но такое скорее всего не нужно.

Напоследок: помните, что вы можете попасть в ситуацию, когда изменения видны там, где не должны быть, в двух случаях: (1) версии .NET старше 4.5 не копируют контекст (и значит, локальные изменения становятся глобальными), (2) копирование происходит лишь на верхнем уровне (не рекурсивно), и значит, изменение внутри объекта становится глобальным. Это приведёт к проблемам для кода, в котором поток выполнения ветвится (например, с `Task.WhenAll`). Поэтому пользуйтесь .NET 4.5+ и неизменяемыми данными!

---

Как подсказывает @Monk, в .NET Core на текущий момент (Core 2.x) нету аналога `CallContext`. Используйте в этом случае [`AsyncLocal<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=netframework-4.7.2), который доступен в .NET Framework 4.6+ и .NET Core 1+. ([Вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31707362/276994) об отличиях между `CallContext` и `AsyncLocal<T>`.)

Comment: Благодарю, отличный ответ.

Comment: @Alexis: И вам спасибо! Ответить на хороший вопрос означает узнать что-то новое (я не знал о стековом поведении, например).

Comment: Попал сюда по упоминанию callcontext, справки пока толковой не нашел нигде. Поможет оно мне с https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/912895/196257 или я копаю не туда? Как этим можно пользоваться?

Comment: @Monk: Ну в принципе это поможет «протащить» объект с конфигурацией через (фреймворковые) функции, которые вашу конфигурацию с собой тащить не планировали. Или там в рамках ASP.NET какой-нибудь dependency container. То есть в принципе это по сути ThreadStatic, только сделанный правильно.

Comment: @Monk: То есть да, таким образом вы можете неявно протащить контекст, не передавая его в каждый метод.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать =)

Comment: @Monk: Отпишитесь по результатам :)

Comment: Получилось, хоть `CallContext` оказывается и не реализован в NetCore. Если интересно - см https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/921703/196257 плюс туда же можно вопросы =)