# Как сделать код контекстно-зависимым, но при этом не передавать контекст явно?

Tags: c#, архитектура

Что есть сейчас:

```
public static Page GetPage(Uri url)
```

Что нужно:

Ограничить число запросов в рамках определенных "контекстов".

1. Это может быть host в параметре url (и это самый просто вариант, можно просто записывать текущие хосты и ограничивать)
2. Может быть "сайт", который хостит разные вещи на разных инстансах облачного провайдера и по хосту их уже не отличить.
3. Может быть сборка запрашивающая метод (т.е. сборке например нельзя этим методом получать больше чем 3 разных страницы в один момент времени)
4. Может быть метод (метод не должен например параллельно делать большую пачку запросов), хотя возможно входит в предыдущий вариант, не продумывал пока детально.

В целом, с одной стороны хочется чтобы когда я делаю условный `godObject.Download()`, а тот делает какие то свои проверки внутри, плюс скачивание, плюс ещё чего-нибудь, чтобы внутри не возникала куча запросов параллельных, с другой - чтобы когда я делаю `simpleClass.DownloadAllLinks()` он мог обработать параллельно пачку ссылок, если на разных ресурсах находятся.

---

Видится это примерно как свойство `Request`, которое в рамках вебсервера есть практически всегда, т.к. обработка запроса и есть весь жизненный цикл. У меня цикл приложения в любом случае какой то тоже есть, например нажатие кнопки пользователем (но оно не будет к сожалению контекстом для скачивания страничек). Но сложить всё это в какую то логическую схему пока не могу.

Переделывать метод на нестатический не хочется, потому что он уже много где используется и явно получить там например экземпляр "контекста" будет нелегко.

Comment: Это искусственный интеллект фактически :)

Comment: @NewView ну почему, я думаю, тут возможны реализации, не могу только придумать, к чему же всё таки цепляться. Вот и задал вопрос, может кто занимался.

Comment: Кажется мне, такое ограничение уже есть в IIS, нужно внимательно пошерстить настройки IIS. "Performance - Limit the kernel request queue" если не ошибаюсь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Основная идея мне пришла давно и в целом, её реализуемость подтвердило это [сообщение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504275/196257)

К сожалению, в netcore пока нет `CallContext`, но [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53211839/3768545) подсказало выход, который при тестировании вел себя аналогично и никаких проблем не выявил.

В итоге, как выглядит код:

```
using (ThrottleService.SetThrottler(new Throttler(15)))
{
  godObject.Download();
}
```

`ThrottleService` просто ставит в `CallContext` экземпляр троттлера, а `GetPage` внутри просто обращается к `CallContext` и проверяет, как там у него с ограничениями.

Отлично сработало с создаваемыми подтасками, внутри троттлера тупо `SemaphoreSlim`.

Из того, что ещё можно сделать - можно вкладывать троттлеры друг в друга, чтобы работали конструкции вида (созданные в разных методах):

```
using (ThrottleService.SetThrottler(new Throttler(15)))
using (ThrottleService.SetThrottler(new Throttler(10)))
```

---

Это решение неплохо заходит с точки зрения прикладной логики - если ты знаешь, что твой код может генерировать много запросов, укажи какое то ограничение.

Тут же кроется и минус - если ты ограничение указал в конкретном месте, то выше по стеку можно только ещё больше ограничить условия, передать только своё ограничение уже не получится. Над этим можно подумать и изобрести костыль, но в целом тут скорее прав [A K](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/916823/196257) и стоит подумать над рефакторингом. Пока, в целях ускорения решения задачи я скорее скомбинирую код - добавлю и решение с `CallContext` и добавлю возможность явно передавать троттлер, для случаев когда он и так под рукой имеется.

Comment: Не то, чтобы я сторонник подобного подхода, но кажется, что вы выкрутились вполне неплохо. Положил себе в закладки.

Comment: Ага, понял! Но тогда может быть вам нужен и правда `ThreadLocal` (или стек в `ThreadLocal`)?

Comment: @VladD скачивание может выполняться в много потоков, `ThreadLocal` же работает в рамках потока?

Comment: @Monk: Да, только в рамках потока. Но есть `AsyncLocal`, который и используется в том примере.

Comment: @VladD вот `AsyncLocal` как раз и использую, да.

Answer (score 1):

Сталкивался с аналогичными задачами в рамках "качаем сайты" или "делаем запросы к СМЭВ" и в общем-то не понимаю сути вопроса. Вам ничего не мешает внутри вашего метода расположить любую логику "не более трёх запроов в секунду на такой-то домен и не более пяти на другой" и ставить в очередь запросы, которые пока невозможно обработать по ограничениям.

Ведь вы и сами понимаете положа руку на сердце, что пошли по кривой тропке, где ваш объект всё больше становится god object - и понимаете, что переделка сигнатуры метода уже дастся немалой кровью — но пока не готовы вернутся на правильную дорогу. Что ж, идите дальше — просто дальше цена будет лишь больше.

По мне вам просто нужно решиться на нормальный рефакторинг. Видел много людей, которые долго собираются с мыслью пойти к стоматологу, а потом удивляются, чего же это они раньше не пошли. Тут что-то похожее. Вам пока не поздно — отрефакторьте по-уму, самому же потом проще будет, особенно когда будете добавлять отдельные потоки/обработчики, каждый из которых будет свою прокси иметь, свои очереди и полиси.

Мне видится это как полноценный объект, который умеет принимать ссылку в очередь и умеет работать с политиками очереди. Ну и пашет себе где-то в отдельном от UI потоке.

Comment: Как и любой рефакторинг - надо найти желание и ресурсы, а никакой выгоды не даст. Идея понятна, но врядли соберусь переписать кучу кода просто так. Да, если появится вопрос с проксями и прочими специфичными вещами - надо будет переписать.